# How to replace 'numeric' and '.' at the same time

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, stringr

In R dataframe, I want to replace all numeric and '.' to 'other'.
Here is the code as blow, there are two method (I want two way to solver it).
Anyone can help ? Thanks!

```
library(tidyverse)

test_data <- data.frame(category = c('.', '2.1', '2.33', 'A', 'B'))

#method 1
test_data %>% mutate(category = str_replace_all(category, "![A-B]", "other"))

#method 2
test_data %>% mutate(category = str_replace_all(category, "(.)|(\d.*)", "other"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape `.` and `\d` properly in your second example.

```r
test_data %>%
  mutate(category = str_replace_all(category, "(\\.)|(\\d.*)", "other"))
#>   category
#> 1    other
#> 2    other
#> 3    other
#> 4        A
#> 5        B
```

Comment: Just to make it clear, what this code output is with these data: `c('.', '2.1', '2.33', 'A', 'B.01')`?

Answer (score 2):

Similar to solution proposed by @caldwellst, arguably more readable:

```
gsub('^(\\d|\\.)+$', 'other', test_data$category)

# [1] "other" "other" "other" "A"     "B"
```